# how to add an object in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

let's say I have the following code:

```
var cont = <div id="foo">

imgSection.find('video').each(function(_ind)
{
     cont.append('<div class="fullScreenBg"> '+ $(this) +' </div>');
});
```

which results in:

```
<div id="foo"> 
<div class="fullScreenBg"> [object Object] </div>
</div>
```

But I actually want do display the html of the Object/Video. When I use instead:

```
$(this).html()
```

I get pretty close, but it shows, as expected, only the innerHtml of the videoTag.
So how do I do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `video` element in the `div` and append the object. The issue at the moment is that you are appending the object as a string which is causing the object to string conversion, resulting in `[object Object]`.

```
imgSection.find('video').each(function(_ind) {
     cont.append($(this).wrap('<div class="fullScreenBg"></div>').parent());
});
```

Comment: booom! thats my answer! I would never ever had found this solution, thanks a million times!

Comment: I'm still not allowed to upvote, but will surely accept your answer as soon stackoverflow let's me do so - stupid timer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, create DOM elements instead of using HTML:

```
var $parent = $('<div class="fullScreenBg" />');
$parent.append(this).appendTo(cont);
```

Comment: huh, interesting. I'll keep that in mind, though Rory McCrossans answer looks a little more elegant to me.